# LaTeX Error: File `ubuntu.sty' not found

Tags: fonts, pdftex, ubuntu

I am running Winedt10.3 on miktex under windows 10. I like to use the ubuntu font for my project report. I have installed the ubuntu fonts family from [Ubuntu Font for windows](http://font.ubuntu.com/).

However when I am trying to use

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,chapterprefix=TRUE]{scrbook}
\usepackage[none]{ubuntu}
\fontUbuntuLight, \fontUbuntuMedium or \fontUbuntuCondensed \fontUbuntu
\usepackage{calrsfs}
%standard
\usepackage{trajan}
```

I am getting the above error. As I am using pdftex so I cannot use

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Ubuntu}
```

Please help.

Comment: As far as I know there is no ubuntu font package for pdfLaTeX. Intsalling the font under windows does not create any package for pdfLaTeX or make the font usable by pdfLaTeX. So if you want to use this font as it is in your computer you have to use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX which is not any dificult at all!

Comment: there is an 11 years old repo with type1 fonts and support for pdflatex here https://github.com/tzwenn/ubuntu-latex-fonts. I have no idea how good it is.

Comment: Thanks Fischer, although a bit crude way, but it still worked for me.